# Junos Pulse Workaround?

Tags: networking, vpn

My institution recently switched from using Juniper Network Connect to Junos Pulse.  Under Network Connect there is a series of solutions for connecting to VPNs from Linux using Network Connect, but there seems to be no equivalent set of instructions for connecting to systems that only offer Junos Pulse.

So, I have 2 questions, either I'd be happy having answered:

1. Are there any solutions for connecting to Junos Pulse-only VPNs?
2. If not, does anyone have any advice for creating one, perhaps in light of the fact that there is an Android app for connecting to Pulse VPNs?